# Yacc/Lex: Rejecting symbols not defined

Tags: bison, flex-lexer, yacc, lex, lexical-analysis

I was just wondering whether its possible to make YACC report a syntax error on all symbols not defined in a LEX file.

Eg.

Lex file

```
/*dummy.l*/
%{
#include "dummy.tab.h"

%%

int    return INT;
[a-z]+ return ID;
[0-9]+ return NUM;

%%
```

Yacc file

```
/*dummy.y*/
%token INT ID NUM

%% 
var : INT ID "=" NUM ";" 
%%

int main(void) {
    yyparse();
}
```

Say I have these 2 files, how do I make it so that my program will report a syntax error when a

**$**(dollar symbol) appears in the input.

Eg. It will still accept on input

> int a = 234; $

NOTE: I want to reject all symbols that **ARE NOT** defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a lex rule to recognize all input text as some kind of token.  Usually I use:

```
.|\n    return *yytext;
```

as the last pattern in the lex file.  This insures that no input will trigger the lex default `ECHO` action.  If you have another rule for \n (such as to ignore it), you don't need the `\n` here.

Another note -- using `"="` (double quotes) in the yacc file will not do what you want -- you want to use `'='` (single quotes) to match single literal characters.

Comment: `.    ;` rule but I left the action to empty which according to your answer, triggered the default ECHO action. Now it works perfectly. Thank you for your time sir.